# Mongo db 11000 error comes , when their is no unique field define

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have added a form data into mongoDB first time data is save but after that this error come , i dont have any field with unique type

```
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.employees.$employeeId_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.employees.$employeeId_1  dup key: { : null }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.employees.$employeeId_1  dup key: { : null }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

Here is my schema with no unique field

```
var employee =  
    {
        empCode : { type : String  , required : true },
        firstName : { type : String  , required : true },
        lastName : { type : String },
        email :  { type : String  },
        DOJ :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
        DOB :{ type : Date  },
        phoneNo : { type : String },
        authentication : 
            {
                username : { type : String },
                password : { type : String }
            },
        designation : 
            {
                designationID: [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'designation'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }             
            },
        grade : 
            {
                gradeID : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'grade'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },
        Department :
            {
                departmentID : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId ,ref:'department'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },
        manager : 
            {
                managerID : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'employee'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },
        role :
            {   
                roleID : [{type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId , ref:'role'}],
                effFrom :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
                effTo : { type : Date }
            },

        status : {type:Boolean}
    }
```

i couldnt find what field is giving error , please suggest me if you can find the error it will be great help for me thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better if you post your mongo schema.

Comment: There is no `employeeId` in your schema, however, I guess the data in your document contain this `employeeId`. Please check it in db.

Comment: Check with `db.employees.getIndexes()` to get the index information in this document

Comment: i have drop collection from robomongo (mongoDB) and now its working fine

Comment: drop collection? er ....hmmmmmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please drop your collection from mongo db , then execute your code .

Your collection have field employeeID

Comment: Would be better to just drop the index instead of the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that there's already a record with `null` as the `employeeId`. Namely, there is one `employees` without an `employeeId`.

As the document says below:

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.

It seems the `employeeId` of `employees` is `unique index` in your case, change it from `unique index` to `spare index` could fix your issue. Because `unique index` constraint with the `sparse index` to filter these `null` values from the unique index and avoid the error.

Or to remove the index on `emplyeeId` through `db.employees.dropIndex('emplyeeId')`